# Is it faster to dig data using sql_fetch_array or having a csv string and separate the values using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a website that is supposed to show the specifications of computers, for example: Cpu, cpu speed, ram and stuff like that. There are a lot of fields and I wonder whether the php's mysql_fetch_array would be faster or saving all the data in one varchar field and separating it using php? also wondering if there are any pros and cons to either of them?
I'm using php 5.3 and mySQL
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'll use A database but Everything in separates field and tables (DB relational) with a Entity relationship Diagram + normalization. Doing that you will have scalability, Independence, avoid redundancy, beside if you add good INDEX (PK,FK and UK) you could have a good performance.  Of course that will also depend of your queries and your PHP code.  But that's a good practice to implement the right DB design plus security stuff.

The pros are A LOT... the cons, It will take you more time but it will worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the speed difference is ever going matter.  What will matter is whether or not you have a regular structure and the ability to freely query your data.  Put it in the database & figure out how to speed things up later when/if it ever becomes an issue, rather than making poor design decisions up front because you think you might need more performance.